# In Sass, how can I output a % sign

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a family of CSS selectors using a for loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .bottom-#{$i} {
    bottom: #{$i}%;
  }
}
```

I want an output that looks like this:

```
.bottom-1 { bottom: 1%  }
.bottom-2 { bottom: 2%  }
.bottom-3 { bottom: 3%  }
```

But SASS doesn't like the % sign- it's trying to eval the statement. I'm assuming there is a way to escape a character like that, but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @cimmanon Could you show me how to get the output I indicated using the technique used in the duplicate question? It doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [percentage()](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function to convert the number to a percentage and then divide it by `100`:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .bottom-#{$i} {
    bottom: percentage($i / 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you- I didn't realize the percentage function would actually render a '%' sign onto the string.